# Filtering CSV with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm having difficulty filtering this CSV file.

Here are a few entries from the csv table:

```
Name      Info                                 Bio
Alice     Woman: 21y (USA)                     Actress
Breonna   Woman: (France)                      Singer
Carla     Woman: 30y (Trinidad and Tobago)     Actress
Diana     Woman: (USA)                         Singer
```

I'm trying to filter the Info row to get all a list of countries and their frequency. I'm also trying to do the same thing with age. As you can see, not all women post their age.

I've tried

```
women= pd.read_csv('women.csv')
women_count = pd.Series(' '.join(women.Info).split()).value_counts()
```

However, that splits everything and outputs:

```
Woman:     4
(USA)      2
21y        1
(Trinidad  1
and        1
Tobago)    1
30y        1
```

I should add I've tried `women_filtered = women[women['Info'] == '(USA)']` and that doesn't work

My questions are:

1. How can I split the string just to filter by countries especially since all the countries are in parenthesis?
2. How can I filter for entries that do not have age?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
{'Name':['Alice', 'Breonna', 'Carla', 'Diana'],
 'Info':['Woman: 21y (USA)', 'Woman: (France)', 'Woman: 30y (Trinidad and Tobago)', 'Woman: (USA)'],
 'Bio':['Actress', 'Singer', 'Actress', 'Singer']}
)

# defining columns using regex
df['country'] = df['Info'].str.extract('\(([^\)]+)\)')
df['age'] = df['Info'].str.extract('[\s]+([\d]{2})y[\s]+').astype(float)
df['noage'] = df['age'].isnull().astype(int)

# frequency of countries
sizes = df.groupby('country').size()
sizes
```

This will output the frequencies.

```
country
France                 1
Trinidad and Tobago    1
USA                    2
dtype: int64
```

I would lookup how to write regex expressions so you can learn how to extract information from strings yourself. [Pythex.org](http://pythex.org) is a nice website to try out regex expressions in Python and has some useful tips.

Comment: I like this answer. One suggestion: the regex that captures the age should be modified to allow for 1 or 3 digits as well (`'[\s]+([\d]{1,3})y[\s]+'`).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This worked. I will also check out this website you provide. Thank you again for taking the time to answer my question!

Answer (score 1):

print(df)

```
      Name                       Info      Bio
0    Alice           Woman: 21y (USA)  Actress
1    Carla  30y (Trinidad and Tobago)   Singer
2  Breonna            Woman: (France)  Actress
3    Diana               Woman: (USA)   Singer

#Solution



#Extract Name of countries
 df=df.assign(Age=df.Info.str.extract('(\d+(?=\D))'), Countries=df.Info.str.extract('\((.*?)\)'))

Name                       Info             Bio     Age                   Countries
    0    Alice           Woman: 21y (USA)  Actress   21                  USA
    1    Carla  30y (Trinidad and Tobago)   Singer   30  Trinidad and Tobago
    2  Breonna            Woman: (France)  Actress  NaN               France
    3    Diana               Woman: (USA)   Singer  NaN                  USA
    



#Filter without Age
df[df.Age.isna()]

     Name             Info      Bio  Age  Countries
2  Breonna  Woman: (France)  Actress  NaN    France
3    Diana     Woman: (USA)   Singer  NaN       USA
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. This solution partly worked. It outputted the Countries correctly but didn't account for the entires that did not list an age. But I  still really appreciate your answer.

Comment: What do you mean by accounting for entries that do not list age? I can help if clarified

Comment: For instance, for the entry in row 3, when it doesn't leave a blank output for Age

Comment: What do you want it to do? as you can see, the `Age` has been extracted as `NaN`and `Country` as `USA`. That to me looks OK